# .htaccess Redirect Subdirectories to Query Strings

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I've been searching for a while and can't find an answer to my question.

I'm working on a site with multiple locations and for SEO purposes want to be able to use the location in the URL but have it redirect to a common page for all of them.

For example, I want the following URLs to redirect from:

```
www.mysite.com/newyork/page1

www.mysite.com/newyork/page2
```

to:

```
www.mysite.com/page1?location=newyork

www.mysite.com/page2?location=newyork
```

While keeping the URL the same for vanity purposes.

There are also some URLs which would need to redirect additional query strings based on subdirectories, for example:

```
www.mysite.com/newyork/product/productname
```

becomes

```
www.mysite.com/product?location=newyork&name=productname
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly that is possible, actually it is straight forward. So the question is why none of all the answers here on SO provided any help for you. Without you specifying more details, so *why* all those answers did not help, so what specific issue you ran into, all we can do is provide one more answer along the line of all those previous ones:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2?location=$1 [END,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2?location=$1&name=$3 [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported [END] flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older [L] flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's DOCUMENT_ROOT folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).